# AspectJ, separating native library calls from application calls

Tags: aop, aspectj

I am using AspectJ and Load-time weaving to trace methods calls in an arbitrary java program.  I can trace all calls using the standard:

```
call(* *.*(..))
```

But what I now trying to do is separate out calls to the native java libraries and any application code:

```
nativeCalls(): !within(MethodTracer) && call(* java..*.*(..));

appCalls(): !within(MethodTracer) && call(* *.*(..)) && !call(* java..*.*(..));
```

The issue is that the nativeCalls() pointcut is picking out calls to application classes that inherit from native java classes, even though the signatures do not start with java.lang. or java.util, etc.

For example:

If I have a class tetris.GameComponent that inherits from java.awt.Component, my nativeCalls() pointcut will pick out tetris.GameComponent.getBackground() when the method is actually implemented in java.awt.Component.getBackground().

Is there a way to have my nativeCalls() pointcut ignore the calls to inherited methods?

I hope this is clear.  I can provide additional info if necessary.  Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have no idea why you want to exclude those inherited method calls from your trace because IMO it is important or at least interesting to know if a method was called on one of your classes, even if that method was defined in a JDK super class.

But anyway, the answer is no, you cannot exclude calls to JDK methods from your `nativeCalls()` pointcut if those calls are actually made upon target objects typed to one of your application classes. At the time the call is made, AspectJ does not know how the JVM will resolve the polymorphism. There can be several cases:

- Call to `Foo.aaa()`, existing method `Foo.aaa()` is executed. This is the simple case where a called method actually exists.
- Call to `Foo.bbb()`, inherited method `Base.bbb()` is executed (polymorphism). This is the case you want to exclude, but you cannot because the fact that a base method is called will only be known when the method is executed. Furthermore, if `Base` is a JDK class, you cannot even intercept its method executions with AspectJ.
- Call to `Base.ccc()`, non-overridden method `Base.ccc()` is executed. This can happen if you directly create an instance of `Base` or also if you assign/cast a `Foo` instance to a variable typed `Base`, e.g. `Base obj = new Foo()`, and call `obj.ccc()` which has *not* been overridden by `Foo`.
- Call to `Base.ddd()`, overridden method `Foo.ddd()` is executed (polmorphism). This also happens if you assign/cast a `Foo` instance to a variable typed `Base`, e.g. `Base obj = new Foo()`, and call `obj.ddd()` which has been overridden by `Foo`.

So much for not being able to easily exclude the polymorphism stuff when calling inherited JDK method.

Now the other way around: You can easily intercept `execution()` instead of `call()` upon your application classes and take advantage of the fact that JDK method executions cannot be intercepted anyway: `pointcut appMethod() : execution(* *(..));`

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough answer.  I suspected this would not be possible, but it is good to have confirmation.  I will try using execution() to intercept application calls, and use only call() for JDK calls, as you suggest.  Cheers.